# How to Implement custom role management for users in laravel 5.4.6

Tags: php, laravel, web

Hello I am working on custom user role management ( not using laravel built in implementation ) , i have following tables

1- User 
2- Role
3- User_Role

Problem I want to show different layouts according to logged in user on the behalf of current logged in user role.

Here is master layout code

```
<section id="container" class="" style="">

    @include('frontend.header.header')

        @include('frontend.sidebar.sidebar')

        <div class="admin_right_content">
        @section('content')
        @show
    </div>
</section>
```

This layout should be changed according to authenticated user. Actually I want to restrict the user for different layouts, please guide me, thanks

Comment: have you looked into the package [Zicaco/Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) ? it does that out-of-the box

Comment: @Zicaco/Entrust i am new to the laravel that is why working on custom role , please guide me custom , Bassem Lhm yesterday needs is confusing me, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a nice package which can do all of this. So you are using laravel 5.4

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

Documentation [Larave Permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)